# Whats the lowest NodeJs version is required to use Google Drive API V3?

Tags: node.js, google-api, google-drive-api, google-sheets-api, google-api-nodejs-client

I have been told to use NodeJs V4.9.1/NPM 2.5.11 to develop the server side API's and should use google drive/sheet API's for file upload and validating the user's file. Does NodeJs V4.9.1 should support the Google Drive V3 and Google Sheets API V4 ?

Answer (score 1):

The Google drive and google sheets apis are rest apis that means that they are accessed using HTTP calls.

Any programming language or version of a programming language that can make a HTTP Post, HTTP Get, and possibly patch.  will be able to use these apis.

I suspect that who ever told you that was refering to the version of node required for running the [Google apis nodejs clinet library](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-nodejs-client)  I have been unable to find any information on what the minimum version of node required to run that library is.

I have added an issue asking them to clarify that [issues 1348](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-nodejs-client/issues/1348)

Answer (score 0):

If you use the http/REST API directly, then it's your code so you can write to any version of node. If you intend to use Google's JavaScript client library, that requires node >= 6, so will not run on node 4.9.